# How do i convert the Order date to show only the date

Tags: sql-server

Hey I'm trying to convert the date to show  ONLY the date and not the time. Im using AdventureWorksDW2012. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT FIS.CustomerKey, FirstName+ ' ' +LastName AS Customers, MAX(FIS.OrderDate) AS RecentOrderDate
FROM FactInternetSales AS FIS
INNER JOIN DimCustomer AS C
ON FIS.CustomerKey = C.CustomerKey
GROUP BY FIS.CustomerKey, FirstName, LastName
```

I only want it to show the date only. Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Cast it to date: `MAX(CAST(FIS.OrderDate AS DATE))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CONVERT` or `CAST`, like this:

```
CONVERT(DATE, Datetime_Column)

CAST(Datetime_Column AS DATE)
```

And in your query:

```
MAX(CONVERT(DATE, FIS.OrderDate))

MAX(CAST(FIS.OrderDate AS DATE))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(your varchar, RecentOrderDate , 1)
```

The 1 will give you Month/day/year